# Ссылки на параметризуемый тип необходимо параметризовать

Tags: java, generics

```
class DinamicArray {
    int length=0;
    private ArrayElement[] values=new ArrayElement[0];

    <E>void add(E val){
        ArrayElement[] tmp=new ArrayElement[length+1];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) tmp[i]=values[i];
        tmp[length]=new ArrayElement(val);
        length+=1;
        values=tmp;
    }
}
class ArrayElement<E> {
    public E value;
    public ArrayElement(E val){
        value=val;
    }
}
```

Здесь происходит попытка создать массив, способный принять в себя любой тип данных (как наследников Object, так и примитивных типов), как элемент массива выступает класс ArrayElement.
Eclipce выдает нотификацию, что

```
ArrayElement - примитивный тип. Ссылки на параметризуемый тип ArrayElement<E> необходимо параметризовать
```

в строках

```
private ArrayElement[] values=new ArrayElement[0];
ArrayElement[] tmp=new ArrayElement[length+1];
tmp[length]=new ArrayElement(val);
```

Если третью строку еще можно параметризовать переписав ее как

```
tmp[length]=new ArrayElement<E>(val);
```

то первые две не получится, так как мы хотим помещать данные любого типа в DinamicArray.
**Вопрос**: как правильно добиться желаемого результата? То есть принимать данные любого типа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то я не догоняю зачем Вам тут контейнер в виде ArrayElement. Чтобы потенциально хранить объекты любых типов достаточно Object[] и дженерики вам тут не к чему, так как предполагается хранить объекты разных типов (соответственно typesafety нереализуемо и дженерики идут лесом). Примитивные типы вы все равно хранить не сможете, только их объектные аналоги (при этом будет производится автоупаковка, например int -> Integer).

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавили generic не там, где надо, arrayelement - внутренний класс, он ответственный за хранение элементов. Следить за соответствием типов - это задача главного класса - DynamicArray:

```
class ArrayElement
{
   public Object value;

   public ArrayElement ( final Object val )
   {
      value = val;
   }
}

class DinamicArray<E>
{
   int length = 0;
   private ArrayElement [] values = new ArrayElement [0];

   public void add ( final E val )
   {
      final ArrayElement [] tmp = new ArrayElement [length + 1];
      for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
      {
         tmp[i] = values[i];
      }
      tmp[length] = new ArrayElement ( val );
      length += 1;
      values = tmp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Все равно не понимаю смысла наличия ArrayElement, он мне кажется лишним звеном. Вообще не понимаю, зачем такое писать, если всегда достаточно любого Collection<Object> для хранения разнородных объектов.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю, но это минимальные изменения нужные для того, чтоб приведенный код хоть как-то работал :)

Comment: @Mage, например, в качестве учебного задания.

Comment: @jmu, он и так работает, но нотификации мне намекают, что что-то я делаю не так :)

Comment: раз вы на них обращаете внимание значит вы на правильном пути развития :)

Comment: @ReinRaus в следующий раз приводите вначале полный текст вашего учебного задания :)

Comment: Оно в ветке чуть ниже и не мое. Я не знал, что Object может принять примитивный тип, поэтому задумался "Ммм... Любой тип можно принять с помощью generics", и отсюда вытек вопрос :)